# Widget doesn't show in Panel

Tags: uibinder, gwt2, gxt

I'm using **gxt 3.0.1** and **gwt 2.5.1**.
I’ve created `FramedPanel` and `Widget` with `UiBinder` and it works fine. `Widget` inherits from `Composite`. After adding `Widget` to `FramedPanel` it doesn't show up.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]
Main View:

```
    <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.core.client.util.Margins" field="centerMargins">
        <ui:attributes top="4" right="4" bottom="0" left="4" />
    </ui:with>
    <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.MarginData" field="centerData">
        <ui:attributes margins="{centerMargins}" />
    </ui:with>
    <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.core.client.util.Margins" field="middleMargins">
        <ui:attributes top="5" right="0" bottom="5" left="0" />
    </ui:with>
    <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData" field="middleData">
        <ui:attributes margins="{middleMargins}" width="1" height="-1" />
    </ui:with>
    <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.BorderLayoutContainer.BorderLayoutData" field="eastData">
        <ui:attributes minSize="200" maxSize="1000" size="400" margins="{eastMargins}" collapsible="true" split="true" />
    </ui:with>
    <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.core.client.util.Margins" field="eastMargins">
        <ui:attributes top="0" right="1" bottom="0" left="5" />
    </ui:with>
    <core:FramedPanel headerVisible="false">
        <c:BorderLayoutContainer borders="false">
            <c:center layoutData="{centerData}">
                <c:VerticalLayoutContainer ui:field="mainVerContainer">
                    <c:child layoutData="{middleData}">
                        <p:PanView />
                    </c:child>
                </c:VerticalLayoutContainer>
            </c:center>
            <c:east layoutData="{eastData}">
                <core:ContentPanel headingText="" />
            </c:east>
        </c:BorderLayoutContainer>
    </core:FramedPanel>
```

Widget's View:

```
<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.ColumnModel" field="columnModel" />
<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.ListStore" field="store" />
<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.grid.GridView" field="view">
    <ui:attributes stripeRows="true" columnLines="true" />
</ui:with>

<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.MarginData" field="centerData">
    <ui:attributes margins="{centerMargins}" />
</ui:with>

<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.core.client.util.Margins" field="centerMargins">
    <ui:attributes top="0" right="0" bottom="0" left="0" />
</ui:with>

<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData" field="topData">
    <ui:attributes width="1" height="30" />
</ui:with>

<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData" field="middleData">
    <ui:attributes width="1" height="1" />
</ui:with>

<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.core.client.util.Margins" field="southMargins">
    <ui:attributes top="1" right="1" bottom="5" left="1" />
</ui:with>

<ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.BorderLayoutContainer.BorderLayoutData" field="southData">
    <ui:attributes size=".5f" minSize="200" maxSize="1000" margins="{southMargins}" collapsible="true" split="true" />
</ui:with>
<core:ContentPanel headerVisible="false" ui:field="mainPanel" borders="false">
    <c:BorderLayoutContainer borders="false">
        <c:center layoutData="{centerData}">
            <core:ContentPanel headingText="Grid" collapsible="false" ui:field="documentPanel">
                <c:VerticalLayoutContainer borders="false">
                    <c:child layoutData="{topData}">
                        <t:ToolBar ui:field="topToolBar">
                            <b:TextButton ui:field="toPreviousPackageButton" toolTip="Up" />
                            <t:SeparatorToolItem />                                     
                        </t:ToolBar>
                    </c:child>
                    <c:child layoutData="{middleData}">
                        <grid:Grid cm="{columnModel}" store="{store}" view="{view}" loadMask="true" columnReordering="true" borders="false" />
                    </c:child>
                </c:VerticalLayoutContainer>
            </core:ContentPanel>
        </c:center>

        <c:south layoutData="{southData}">
            <core:ContentPanel ui:field="propertiesPanel" headingText="Properties" />
        </c:south>

    </c:BorderLayoutContainer>
</core:ContentPanel>
```

Comment: Provide the java code.